# Return multiple array outputs from function to parameter

Tags: modelica

I have a function that returns two arrays of unequal sizes (A,B). These are for determining initial conditions of a model so I would like for them each to be defined as a `parameter` array in the model. Is this possible and, if so, how?

Below is some pseudo code of the question:

**Function**

```
function myfunc
input Real[:] alpha;
input Real[:] beta;

output Real[size(alpha,1)] A;
output Real[size(beta,1)] B;
algorithm
//equations, etc.
end myfunc;
```

**Model**

```
model mymodel

parameter Real[2] alpha = {1,2};
parameter Real[3] beta = {3,4,5};

parameter Real (A_start,Bstart) = myfunc(alpha,beta)

Real[size(alpha ,1)] A(start=A_start);
Real[size(beta,1)] B(start=B_start);

equation

//equations, etc.

end mymodel;
```

I've tried several things that failed. One successful method used the initial equation section. However, it requires me, for example, to define `A_start` as a variable and to add `der(A_start) = 0` in an equation section, and prevents me from providing a non-fixed guess value (i.e., `A(start=A_start)`) to the variables, which could cause problems.

Thanks for your help, even if its confirming that I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution by Scott G works, but it is also possible to solve in other ways - that may or may not be better. One common idea is as follows:

```
  record R
    Real A[:],B[:];
  end R;

  function bar
    input Real[:] alpha;
   input Real[:] beta;
   output R r(redeclare Real A[size(alpha,1)],redeclare Real B[size(beta,1)]);
  algorithm 
    (r.A,r.B):=myfunc(alpha,beta);
  end bar;

parameter R r=bar(alpha,beta);

Real[size(alpha, 1)] A(start=r.A);
Real[size(beta,1)] B(start=r.B);
```

Comment: I thought there was some way to throw a record at the problem. Wish I could mark two answers as, like you said, don't know which is better. Your answer was more directly in-line with my original thought though so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks Hans.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, the moment you post something you get an epiphany.

By adding some extra info along with the parameter definition allowed me to do what I needed.

```
model mymodel

parameter Real[2] alpha = {1,2};
parameter Real[3] beta = {3,4,5};

// Adding fixed=false was the missing key
parameter Real A_start(fixed=false); 
parameter Real B_start(fixed=false);

Real[size(alpha ,1)] A(start=A_start);
Real[size(beta,1)] B(start=B_start);

initial equation
    (A_start,Bstart) = myfunc(alpha,beta)

equation
//equations, etc.

end mymodel;
```